# Circulation cells and köppen climates of my world

Tags: climate

[image][image]

This world’s average surface temperature is 42°c. Has a day length of 12 hours and 5 minutes. Has an obliquity of 87°. And, has a mainly oxygen/nitrogen atmosphere that is 4.76 the pressure of Earth’s atmosphere at sea level. Also, this world has a diameter of 0.704x that of Earth’s and a gravity 0.672x that of Earth’s.

The brown patchy areas on the map represent highland/mountainous areas. Nothing too extreme but enough to have climate differences and cause rain shadows.

Based on this information, could someone tell me how many circulation cells per hemisphere this world would likely have or even help make a köppen climate map for it?

My current assumption is that the equator would have tropical Af, Am and As/Aw climates along with Cfa in higher elevations. The mid latitudes would have Csa (with the summers being particularly severe) and possibly Cfa climates. Closer to the poles it would be inhospitable desert (BSh and BWh) surrounded by tropical savannah As. The coasts of the equator next to the large northern ocean would be battered by severe hurricanes (perhaps it could be even called the ‘Sea of Hurricanes’).

Comment: An obliquity of 87° means that the planet is spinning on its side, like [Uranus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranus), with month-long days and nights over a large part of the planet; for example, most of the northern ocean will be continuously bathed in sunlight in summer and will be continuously dark in winter. Air circulation won't be similar to Earth's in any way.

Comment: @AlexP Indeed, I found a site that tells me what Earth köppen climates might be like at 90° obliquity: https://worldbuildingpasta.blogspot.com/2022/08/climate-explorations-obliquity.html but this is at 15°c with a longer year length, thinner atmosphere, more surface water and longer day length than my world . My parameters are quite different because there’s other major factors at play too.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is this video. It's pretty helpful and also talks about how many circulation-cells per hemisphere would exist depending on the planet's rotational period. https://youtu.be/LifRswfCxFU?t=164

Comment: Average surface temperature of 42C is ringing a dozen alarm bells in my mind; bear in mind that an average above about 37C in a given region means humans cannot survive long-term without access to air conditioning if there's any real humidity, because they can't sweat to cool off effectively. Earth, as a reference, has an average of 15C, and that produces plenty of deserts and tropical areas. At 42C, I fear your world's oceans will be at risk of literally boiling away and causing an immediate runaway greenhouse effect. Frankly, given a million years, your world is probably a second Venus.

Comment: @Palarran https://worldbuildingpasta.blogspot.com/2022/05/climate-explorations-temperature.html this site shows what Earth climates would be like with temperatures in that range but this is only changing temperature. If we also increase the atmospheric pressure, decrease gravity and diameter and change the obliquity to be near 90°, what would the köppen climates be like then (with the map in my post)?

Comment: One vital piece of information is missing. What is the energy input into this planet? How from from its parent star is it? And how bright is that star?

Comment: @Slarty the world orbits a K-type star every 108 days and the high temperatures are mainly driven by higher insolation (greenhouse effect is similar to Earth)